# Why does this jQuery not work in one place?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have abstracted some jQuery code to handle filtering of tables in my application. In general, the user clicks a link and certain table rows are shown or hidden. The code is below:

```
var filters = $('ul.filters');
var filtersCount = filters.children().length;
if (filtersCount > 2) {
  filters.children(':last-child').css({
    'right':'1px'
  })
}
var target = filters.data('target');

$('a.filter').on('click', function() {
  filters.children().removeClass('active');
  $('.filterable').hide();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parents('li').addClass('active');
  var visibleStates = $this.data('include-filter').split(" ");
  $(visibleStates).each(function(index,state) {
    if (state == "all") {
      $('.filterable').show();
    } else {
      $('.filterable' + '.' + state).show();
    }
  })
  if ($this.data('exclude-filter') !== undefined) {
    var hiddenStates = $this.data('exclude-filter').split(" ");
    $(hiddenStates).each(function(index,state) {
      $('.filterable' + '.' + state).hide();
    })
  }
})
```

This code is used in five places in my application and works in four of them. By stepping through execution, I know the code does work because it filters the elements but eventually all ".filterable" elements on the page are hidden. I have followed the execution of the code which goes into this part of jQuery:

```
if ( ret !== undefined ) {
  if ( (event.result = ret) === false ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

The line which causes the ".filterable" rows to be hidden is this:

```
ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );
```

Eventually, execution stops on this line:

```
return event.result;
```

`event.result` is undefined if I look at it in the console. Javascript is not really my area of expertise so if anyone can give me a point in the right direction, I would be grateful.

EDIT

I have added the simplest code possible into my table as follows with the same result. Both rows are hidden and don't reappear irrespective of which filter link I click.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="filterable paid-sick-leave">
    <td>From</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="filterable paid-annual-leave">
    <td>From</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The filters look like this. The Ruby code prints out the description of the absence category, downcasing it and replacing spaces with hyphens.

```
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="filter" data-include-filter="all">All Absences</a>
  </li>
  <% @absence_categories.each do |ac| %>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="filter" data-include-filter="<%= ac.description.downcase.gsub(' ','-') %>"><%= ac.description %></a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us the markup? How is the last instance different from the first four that causes it to break? If you have 6 tables, do the last two remain broken? Or just the last one? Have you tried duplicating the last table and moving it to the first, does it break? There are so many ways to check what could’ve went wrong.

Comment: You are using an anchor for the filter, could it be that it has an href attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this click event like below:

```
$(document).on('click','a.filter', function() {
  filters.children().removeClass('active');
  $('.filterable').hide();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parents('li').addClass('active');
  var visibleStates = $this.data('include-filter').split(" ");
  $(visibleStates).each(function(index,state) {
    if (state == "all") {
      $('.filterable').show();
    } else {
      $('.filterable' + '.' + state).show();
    }
  })
  if ($this.data('exclude-filter') !== undefined) {
    var hiddenStates = $this.data('exclude-filter').split(" ");
    $(hiddenStates).each(function(index,state) {
      $('.filterable' + '.' + state).hide();
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! So I understand this is about delegated events. But I would normally use those when I am dynamically creating elements in the page. I'm loading my js after the body has rendered so I can't see why that would be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It mean "event.result" is Null you need to test if your event click still exist after you need to debug in the console script as application step by step may be this error caused by no reference class or html.